# CAPTCHA for jQuery + Pyramid?

Tags: jquery, captcha, pyramid

I'm looking for an example of implementing CAPTCHA with jQuery and Pyramid as the server side (without PHP essentially).

Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a Python client for recaptcha:

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9280595/708221) on another post.

Than instead of putting the widget in a regular form, if you want to submit it using jquery, just read the values from the generated elements.