# Pyramid with reCaptcha: how to implement?

Tags: captcha, recaptcha, pyramid

I want to add the most popular captcha client on my site - reCaptcha.
But I didn't found any examples or tutorials in internet...
Maybe somebody knows how to do it?

I'll be very appreciate for any help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is full API documentation available for reCATPCHA [here](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/display.html). It probably has sample code, too.

I found this by going to the [reCAPTCHA website](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/) and clicking on the [FAQ](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/faq) link.

And of course, you sign up for the service [here](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/whyrecaptcha). That's pretty obvious from the home page.

Comment: Yes, I did it within 2 hours! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things:

1) Display the widget on your site. Copy the html and javascript code [on this reCaptcha documentation page](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/display.html).

2) Validate the user's response. You can use the [python client](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/recaptcha-client) for this.
There is an example on how to use this in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440239/how-to-use-python-plugin-recaptcha-client-for-validation).

Good luck!